# PostQuitMessage() Undefined?

Tags: c++, winapi

I have been working through a basic windows programming tutorial, and got stuck when using *PostQuitMessage(0);*, where the compiler claims that it is undefined. I believe that the problem is that I am missing a namespace or some library, but cannot figure it out. Also highly note that *PostQuitMessage()* is not the only undefined function, others include: *DefWindowProc()*, *WNDCLASSEX*, and *GetClientRect()*. I am using Visual Studio 2015 with a cleaned DirectX 11 project template. Any help is very much appreciated. The below is my code:

```
#include <Windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM
lParam)
{
    if (uMsg == WM_DESTROY)
    {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }

    DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE prevInst, LPWSTR cmd, int 
nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX windowClass;

    return 0;
}
```

(Yes I understand that the code is not nearly finished, I just wanted to solve these errors before I continue.)

Comment: You're making a desktop app, right? For universal apps they removed a lot of the Windows API, because (AFAIK) they want you to use .NET.

Comment: @immibis Yes I am.

Comment: You don't have more than one file called "windows.h" somehow?

Comment: What's the exact error message?

Comment: Your question should include the exact error message

Comment: Without the error message it's unclear what you are asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this blog:

[Introducing the Universal CRT](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/03/03/introducing-the-universal-crt/)

You need to make sure your project is linked with the Universal CRT DLL (ucrt.dll). So make sure you update the additional include directory to point to where the ucrt headers are, and the additional library directory to point to the ucrt lib files.

```
    $(UniversalCRT_IncludePath)
    $(UniversalCRT_LibraryPath_x86)
    $(UniversalCRT_LibraryPath_x64)
    $(UniversalCRT_LibraryPath_arm)
```

NOTE - the Macros don't always expand to the correct UCRT location. 
So you need to check your system for the actual paths. On my system, I am using the below:

**For include path:**

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10586.0
```

**For the Lib path:**

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.10586.0\ucrt
```

Depending on the version of the SDK you have installed, **it may be different**.

To add the include files:

```
Project properties --> C/C++ --> General --> Additional Include Directories
```

To add the lib files:

```
Project properties --> Linker --> General --> Additional Library Directories 

(Or Properties --> VC++ Directories --> Library Directories)
```

Comment: "So long as you do not link with the /nodefaultlib option, all of the correct library files will be found when you link your project. "

Comment: Regardless, PostQuitMessage is *not a CRT function* - it's from user32.

Comment: @kvr where do I include these links? I am guessing in the project properties under Linker, but where from there?

Comment: [Project properties --> C/C++ --> General --> Additional Include Directories]
[Project properties --> Linker --> General --> Additional Library Directories] (Or Properties --> VC++ Directories --> Library Directories)

Comment: @Synthetic also try a vanilla non Direct-X based project and see if the issue is just isolated to that project template.

Comment: @kvr I believe I am almost there, I do not have experience with the linker and require a tad more help. So I added all of the $(Univ...) to the Include and Lib path, but what are you saying to do with the system path? (C:\...)

Comment: @Synthetic the '$(UniversalCRT_IncludePath)' are just macros which expand to actual file paths on your system. So I was saying to look at your file system to make sure that the Macro is using the correct path. Once you enter the '$(UniversalCRT_IncludePath)' into Visual Studio it tells you which file location it references in the same Window where it was added. Can you check if it's referencing the correct file locations on your system?

Comment: @kvr I use the same path as you do, so yes.

Comment: @kvr So a Blank Project in VS works perfectly, just a problem in linking.

Comment: MSDN says that it's in `usr32.dll`, not in some Visual C specific run-time library.

Comment: @Synthetic yes it seems so, following similar approach you can find out where the actual Windows.h header files reside on your system and add them to your include paths and should have similar effect.

Comment: @Synthetic - in your generic test project, also try adding #include <Windows.h> and a test api and see if that also complains. Not sure if you already did in the vanilla test project, so wanted to mention it incase adding the Windows header there errors out the same way.

Comment: @kvr I did and I comes up clean, I just took a screenshot of the linker page in the working project and will replicate it in my DX project.

Comment: @kvr I seem to be stumped on this one, I will just move my project files to a new blank project.

Answer (score 0):

The MSDN online documentation indicates which DLL is required for a given function.

For [PostQuitMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644945%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) it indicates that you link `usr32.lib` (in order to pull in `usr32.dll` at run time).

I found this by typing `MSDN PostQuitMessage` into Google and clicking on the first result.

Answer (score -2):

`PostQuitMessage()`, `DefWindowProc()`, `GetClientRect()`, `WNDCLASSEX`, these are all from the Win32 API, and they are all declared in `winuser.h`, which is `#include`'d by `windows.h`.  So make sure that the `Windows.h` file you are `#include`'ing in your code is actually the *correct* file for the Win32 API and not someone else's version in a separate library/SDK your project happens to be referring.

Comment: @immibis: I understand that, but that does not guarantee that the OP is including the *correct* `windows.h` file.  The capital `W` is suggestive that maybe the OP is including a different file.

Comment: I believe that there is no other "Windows.h" file included in my project, if there was the WINAPI would register as an error, which it doesn't.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Actually, Microsoft's Windows.h file has a capital W. Of course, you're free to use a lowercase w, given that it's a case-insensitive OS.

Comment: @immibis: every compiler that I have worked with that includes the Windows SDK has a lowercase 'windows.h' file. You are right about the case-sensitivity.  But every Win32 tutorial and code example I have seen over the years uses a lowercase `windows.h` in the `#include`, so it makes me wonder why the OP is using `Windows.h` instead. Oh well.

Comment: @RemyLebeau MSVS auto-completes to Windows.h